# Prevent python script from crashing with try/except using instapy-cli library

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, instagram, instagram-api

I am using a python library that posts to instagram (instapy-cli). However, this will be for an installation and if the wifi cuts out I still want the script to run even if the upload doesn't work. I have wrapped it in a try/except but if the function crashes, it still ends the script.

Here's my code

```
try:
    with client(username,password) as cli:
        cli.upload(fileName, text)
except Exception as e:
    print(e.output)
```

In the console I get below mentioned error:

> ClientError URLError 
>   urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed> (Code: 0, Response: )

Before I had the code:

```
try:
    subprocess.call([r'filePath/insta.bat', fileName, caption])
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e)
```

which worked exactly as I wanted (if no wifi the script kept running and it failed silently)

Comment: so if upload fails, you want to attempt to upload it again? right now the script ends because there's nothing else left to do after printing `e.output`

Comment: so if the upload fails, i want to continue with the script as none of my other code will be impacted. also, it's not printing the error in the console

Comment: The script, as written, will continue the execution regardless of whether there was an exception or not (unless `BaseException` is raised, which is not supposed to happen).

Comment: weird, because my entire script terminates and the opencv windows im showing close

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: Is there any code in the script _after_  the included fragment? If so, are you sure that code is not executed?

Comment: @DYZ yes, there is code after this script that should be running.

Comment: Are you sure you also do not see a message `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: AttributeError: 'URLError' object has no attribute 'output'`? Because `e.output` is illegal.

Comment: OK, I ran a similar piece of code (but changed `e.output` to `e`), and got a similar error printout in the exception handles (`<urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>`) and the were no further exceptions.

Comment: @DYZ inside the instapy-cli source code, I found exit(9) when there is a ClientError so I'm assuming that's the problem. Prob need my own fork of the repo now

Comment: Three advices: 1) Assume that Python works, so if if it doesn't it's something else 2) Is the problem the problem elsewhere? (`except Exception` catches _everything_) 3) When all else fails, start "wiggling" your code: introduce print statements or even meaningless things that will let you learn things about the context.

Comment: @fralau inside the instapy-cli source code, I found exit(9) when there is a ClientError so I'm assuming that's the problem. Prob need my own fork of the repo now

Comment: Woah. That's a funny "elsewhere". Make sure that's the correct diagnosis; but if that's the case, then that code is ill-behaved, because a library is not supposed to crash out like this. The best thing, if you know how to fork a project on github, is to _fix_ it. I would avoid working my way around a library that doesn't work well: fix it, or find/write another one. BTW, there is an easier solution ("hot glue") that you could try first: just monkey patch the class by rewriting just the function in a proper way.

Comment: @fralau it was a fairly complex function so i forked the repo and commented out the exit function, works like a charm now!

Comment: Two last things: 1) if you haven't done so yet, let the good guys who wrote the library know what you did, by opening an issue on github. 2) thanks for your contribution to make this world a better place.

Comment: @fralau Done and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug into the source code of the library instapy-cli and found in the upload function:

```
except ClientLoginError as e:
    print('ClientLoginError {0!s}'.format(e))
    exit(9)
```

So I forked the repo, commented out the exit function, uninstalled the library, and reinstalled my forked version. Worked like a charm!